# FFmpeg move video on overlay in fixed coordinates

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video (A) placed on the background video (B). I want video A to rotate around video B or left to right and back right to left.
I tried code:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i "Filter_HD.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=840:460 [v1]; [2:v]scale=840:460 [v2]; [v1][v2]overlay=0:0 [v3]; [1:v]boxblur=9:8,scale=1280:720 [v4]; [v4][v3]overlay=enable='between(t,1,8*60)':x='if(lte(-w+(t)*50,w/11),-w+(t)*50,w/2)':y=100[out],setdar=16/9" -map "[out]" -threads 0 -preset superfast out.mp4
```

But it moves and does not repeat.
Please help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need to move video1 from x=A to x=B (both measured from left edge of video2) and back at a rate of R pixels/sec.

Use overlay `x` expression,

```
x='A+min(mod(t,2*(B-A)/R)*R,2*(B-A)-mod(t,2*(B-A)/R)*R)'
```

Comment: Thank you,I'm very grateful for your help